# What am I doing wrong in displaying data? - Ionic 3 & Firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2

I'm having trouble displaying some Firebase data in my Ionic 3 app. Here's the relevant code from my component (the abcdef part is just a substitute for a particular user's key):

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('/profiles/abcdef/');
this.viewProfile = ref.once("value")
  .then(function(snapshot) {
    var firstName = snapshot.child("firstName").val();
    var lastName = snapshot.child("lastName").val();
    var orgName = snapshot.child("orgName").val();
    console.log(firstName+' '+lastName+' works at '+orgName );
  });
```

And here's what I have in the view:

```
{{viewProfile.firstName}}
```

No error, simply nothing displays. Any ideas?

Comment: did you check console? whether the names are printing or not?

Comment: try adding async {{viewProfile.firstName | async}}

Comment: Yes I should have mentioned that - the console does display all of the variables correctly, but I can't get any to display properly in the page template itself. And unfortunately, adding async did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop the `snapshot` to get the data

try this

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('/profiles/abcdef/');
ref.once("value")
  .then(function(snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
          this.viewProfile = data.val();
      }
 });
```

Comment: Actually, snapshot.child("firstName").val() did indeed work as far as displaying each variable in the console, as did your solution. However, neither worked in terms of displaying the data in the page template.

Comment: you need `async` pipe for it. Please show the code how you done.

Comment: @PrithiviRaj suggested it

Comment: Component: `var ref = firebase.database().ref('/profiles/abcdef/');
        this.viewProfile = ref.once("value")
          .then(function(snapshot) {
            var firstName = snapshot.val().firstName;
            var lastName = snapshot.val().lastName;
            var orgName = snapshot.val().orgName;
            console.log(firstName+' '+lastName+' works at '+orgName );
         });`

Comment: Template: `{{viewProfile.firstName | async}}`

Comment: Again, the variables display properly in the console, just not in the template.

Comment: Here's a potential solution that seems to be working:  
  
Component:  
`const profileRef: firebase.database.Reference =   firebase.database().ref('/profiles/abcdef/firstName');  
        profileRef.on('value', profileSnapshot => {  
          this.viewProfile = profileSnapshot.val();  
        });`  
  
Template:  
`{{viewProfile}}`  
  
But I'd have to create one of these for every variable I want to display, and it would be better to just do this once and call the child data as needed.

Comment: so your `this.viewProfile` not receiving data, try `return snapshot.val()`  inside your `.then()` check using async

Answer (score 1):

You were very close @Hareesh:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('/profiles/abcdef/');
    ref.on('value' , profileSnapshot => {
              this.viewProfile = profileSnapshot.val();
     });
```

and

```
{{viewProfile.firstName}}
```

(no async needed) seems to work.

Thank you!!!